# Number of ring automorhism of $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, cyclic-groups, ring-isomorphism

What are Ring automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_4 ?$ As per the theory, since it's a cyclic group, it depends on the image of the generating element 1.

so there are two possiblities, $\phi(1)=1, \phi(1)=3$

But the isomorphic property says, the map should take identity to identity i.e $\phi(1)=1.$

So in that case $\phi(1)=3$ becomes invalid. Am I correct?

Comment: "But the property says ..."  Which property is that?  You haven't said.

Comment: properties of isomorphisms.

Comment: Could you explicitly quote this "property of isomorphisms"?  (There are many such and it would be unfair to guess which one you mean since it would be easy to guess wrongly.)

Comment: it's mentioned, the property says that the isomorphic map should take identity element in the domain to the identity element in the co- domain.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing thoughts about group isomorphisms and ring isomorphisms.

When you think of the map $1 \mapsto 3$, you must have $1^2 \mapsto 3^2 = 1$, but $1 = 1^2$, so in the image, we are forced to have $3 = 1$, which is not true in $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$.

What you have written about having two isomorphisms is correct for the abelian group of integers modulo $4$ under addition.  As just shown, it is not the case that both maps preserve the multiplication, essentially for the ring isomorphism reason you mention:  the multiplicative identity must be mapped to the multiplicative identity.

Comment: i mean isomorphism takes multiplicative identity to multiplicative identity.

Comment: @Logistics : Swapped that around to the ring point of view.

Comment: can you explain elaborate ?